# How to escape percentage character in msbuild script?

Tags: msbuild

I use following command in msbuild file:

`<Exec Command='net use \\myshare /user:$(USR) "$(PSW)"'/>`

Unfortunately it doesn't work if PSW contains % character. I need to double it. How to do it? I tried $(PSW).replace('%','%%') , but it didn't do what I hoped for.

Comment: Try using `^` as the escape character. e.g. `$(PSW).replace('%','^%')`

Comment: Mind you, that the syntax is wrong anyway. It should be `$(PSW.Replace(...))`. If you do `$(PSW).Replace(...)` you'll the value of PSW followed by the string literal `.Replace(...)`.